# CoreBluetooth[WARNING] has no restore identifier but the delegate implements

Tags: xcode, bluetooth

I'm using the CoreBluetooth but I got this warning message in the output.

CoreBluetooth[WARNING]  has no restore identifier but the delegate implements the centralManager:willRestoreState: method. Restoring will not be supported!

I'm using this code:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey, nil];

myCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:options];
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to make use of CoreBluetooth's save/restore feature, or no? see "Opt In to State Preservation and Restoration" section in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is in regards to CoreBluetooth's save/restore optional feature, see "Opt In to State Preservation and Restoration" part of the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) for more details.

What looks to be happening is that you are implementing the right delegate method to use this feature but you are not providing a restoration identifier in your call to initialize the `CBCentralManager`.

There are two options to resolve the warning:

1. If you want to use this feature you should provide a string identifier that represents the central or peripheral manager to CBCentralManager like so:

   ```
   myCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil
        options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:
        @"myCentralManagerIdentifier" }];
   ```
2. If you don't want to use this feature then remove the `centralManager:willRestoreState:` method from your delegate.

Doing either one should resolve your warning.